# ¿Cómo recibir fechas a través de AJAX en página PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html5, ajax

Tengo un formulario que es enviado a través de un evento AJAX. El mismo contiene varios campos entre los cuales están dos campos de fecha tipo `datetime-local`, los cuales son recibidos en el archivo que contiene todo el código JS de manera correcta (utilizando la sintaxis `'fecha: $('#fecha').val()'`) ya que lo he verificado por consola imprimiendo todos los datos del arreglo asociativo que recibe los datos del formulario.
El problema está en que todos los datos son recibidos exceptuando los dos campos que envían fechas, dando un error de `undefined index`, cosa que me parece extraña ya que las variables que guardan las fechas están correctamente definidas.
Adjunto el código y espero que puedan ayudarme. De antemano, gracias.

```js
$('#formRegistroPostproduccion').submit( function (e) {

        const datosPost = {

            'proyecto': $('#proyecto').val(),
            'tarea': $('#tarea').val(),
            'postproductor': $('#postproductor').val(),
            'otroPostproductor': $('#otroPostproductor').val(),
            'fechaInicio': $('#fechaInicio').val(),
            'fechaFinal': $('#fechaFinal').val(),
            'realizado': $('#realizado').val(),
            'descripcion': $('#descripcion').val(),
            'dep': $('#dep').val(),
            'action': $('#action').val()

        }

        $.post('http://localhost/seguimiento/controlador/controlSave.php', datosPost, function (response) {

            $('#registrado').html(response);
            $('#registrado').removeClass('desaparecer');
            showRegistros();
            $('#formRegistroProduccion').trigger('reset');

        });

        e.preventDefault();

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<?php

error_reporting(0);

require_once('../modelo/conexion.php');
require_once('../modelo/consultas.php');

$consulta = new Consultas();
$rowsPostproductor = $consulta -> getPostproductor();

?>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf8">
    <meta name="keywords" content="pdf, seguimiento">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>ConcienciaTV - Seguimiento Producción</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/icon" href="../img/isotipo.png">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/estilos.css?v=<?php echo(rand()); ?>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/media.css?v=<?php echo(rand()); ?>">

</head>

<body class="contentForm postContent">

        <form id="formRegistroPostproduccion" method="post" action="../prueba.php" class="formulario morado" autocomplete="on">

            <div class="encabezadoForm">

                <h1>Seguimiento Postproducción</h1>

            </div>

            <div class="divRegistrado desaparecer" id="registrado"></div>

            <div class="content">

                <label class="label morado" for="proyecto">Proyecto</label>
                <input class="campos morado focus-morado" type="text" name="proyecto" id="proyecto" required="" placeholder="Proyecto">
                <label class="label morado" for="tarea">Tarea Específica</label>
                <input class="campos morado focus-morado" type="text" name="tarea" id="tarea" required="" placeholder="Tarea Específica">
            
                <label class="label morado" for="responsable">Postproductor</label>
                <select class="selectPostproductor morado" name="postproductor" id="postproductor">
            
                    <?php

                        foreach($rowsPostproductor as $row){

                            echo '<option value="'.$row['idPersonal'].'">'.$row['nombre'].' '.$row['apellido'].'</option>';

                        }

                    ?>

                    <option value="otro">Otro</option>
            
                </select>

                <label class="label morado" id="labelOtroPostproductor" for="otroPostproductor" style="display: none;">Postproductor</label>
                <input class="campos morado" type="hidden" id="otroPostproductor" name="otroPostproductor" placeholder="Postproductor">

                <label class="label morado" for="fechaInicio">Fecha de Inicio de Semana</label>
                <input class="fechas bg-input-gradient-morado morado" type="datetime-local" name="fechaInicio" id="fechaInicio" max="6:00:00 p. m.">
                <label class="label morado" for="fechaFinal">Fecha de Culminación de Semana</label>
                <input class="fechas bg-input-gradient-morado morado" type="datetime-local" name="fechaFinal" id="fechaFinal">
            
                <label class="label morado" for="realizado">Realización</label>
                <input class="opciones" type="radio" name="realizado" id="realizado" value="sí"><strong class="strongOpciones morado">Sí</strong>
                <input class="opciones" type="radio" name="realizado" id="realizado" value="no"><strong class="strongOpciones morado">No</strong>
           
                <label class="label morado" for="descripcion">Descripción de La Tarea Realizada</label>
                <textarea class="areaTexto morado" rows="2" name="descripcion" id="descripcion"></textarea>
                <strong id="contador" class="contador"></strong>

                <input type="hidden" id="dep" value="postproduccion">
                <input type="hidden" id="action" value="registrar">

                <input type="submit" name="btn" class="btnSubmit bg-input-gradient-morado border-morado" value="Registrar">

            </div>

            <?php $var = 'preview'; ?>

            <div class="divAcciones">

                <button id="generar" class="bg-input-gradient-morado border-morado">Generar PDF</button>
                <a target="_blank" class="bg-input-gradient-morado border-morado" href="../pdf/pdf.php?v=<?php echo $var; ?>">Previsualizar PDF</a>
                <a target="_blank" class="bg-input-gradient-morado border-morado" href="temporales.php">Ver datos actuales</a>

            </div>

        </form>

        <script src="../script/jquery.min.js?v=<?php echo(rand()); ?>"></script>
        <script src="../script/app.js?v=<?php echo(rand()); ?>"></script>
        <script src="../script/functions.js?v=<?php echo(rand()); ?>"></script>

</body>
```

```
$msj = null;

    $proyecto = $_POST['proyecto'];
    $tarea = $_POST['tarea'];
    $postproductor = $_POST['postproductor'];
    $fechaInicio = $_POST["fechaInicio"];
    $fechaFinal = $_POST["fechaFinal"];
    echo var_dump($_POST['fechaFinal']);
    $fechaInicio = substr($fechaInicio, 0, 10);
    $fechaFinal = substr($fechaFinal, 0, 10);
    $descripcion = $_POST["descripcion"];
    $realizado = $_POST['realizado'];

    if($postproductor == 'otro'){

        $postproductor = $_POST['otroPostproductor'];

    }

    $fechaInicioInt = strtotime($fechaInicio);
    $fechaInicio = date('Y-m-d', $fechaInicioInt);

    $fechaFinalInt = strtotime($fechaFinal);
    $fechaFinal = date('Y-m-d', $fechaFinalInt);

    if(strlen($proyecto) > 0 && strlen($tarea) > 0 && strlen($postproductor) > 0 
    && strlen($fechaInicio) > 0 && strlen($fechaFinal) > 0 && strlen($realizado) > 0 
    && strlen($descripcion) > 0 && strlen($departamento) > 0){

        $consultas = new Consultas();
        $rows = $consultas -> getDepartamento($departamento);
        $codigos = $consultas -> findCodigosRegistrosPost($postproductor);

        foreach($rows as $row){

            $dep = $row['idDepartamento'];

        }

        foreach($codigos as $codigoRegistro){

            $codigo = $codigoRegistro['codigoPersonal'];
    
        }

        $msj = $consultas -> registroTemporalPost($proyecto, $tarea, $postproductor, $fechaInicio, $fechaFinal, $descripcion, $realizado, $dep, $codigo);
        $consultas -> registroPost($proyecto, $tarea, $postproductor, $fechaInicio, $fechaFinal, $descripcion, $realizado, $dep, $codigo);

        echo "Registro Realizado Correctamente";

    } else {

        echo "Error al Realizar el Registro";

    }
```

Comment: ¿Te refieres a estos dos: `'fechaInicio': $('#fechaInicio').val(), 'fechaFinal': $('#fechaFinal').val()`? Pon un `console.log(datosPost);` en el cliente y un `var_dump($_POST);` en el servidor, revisa la consola y luego pulsa en [edit] y dinos qué muestra cada uno.

Comment: Esas me refiero. El ```console.log(datosPost)``` imprime todos los datos del array. Ya hago un ```var_dump($_POST)``` a ver.

Comment: Muestra ambas salidas en la pregunta para revisar. ¿No estarán quedando vacíos esos `input`?